# How do I explicitly not support pickling?

Tags: python, pickle

I have written a Python class that cannot possibly support pickling. Still, every now and then a user tries to pickle instances of this class, which leads to confusing errors. Therefore I wish to throw a custom, informative error message whenever any attempts to pickle instances of my class are made.

How do I best go about doing this?
I am particularly interested in solutions that have a broad coverage, i.e., do not only work for the standard-library `pickle` but also for alternatives to it.

*As to what I’ve found so far, I’ll write [a self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021038/2127008), but I am not sure whether that’s the best way.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the documentation, I gathered that if the class has a [`__getstate__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) method, it will be called when a pickling attempt is made. Therefore, a solution is to overwrite this method to raise an exception, for example:

```
import pickle

class Foo(object):
    def __getstate__(self):
        raise pickle.PickleError("No pickling for Foo.")
```

This appears to work:

```
some_foo = Foo()
try:
    pickle.dumps(some_foo)
except pickle.PickleError:
    print("Error raised.")
else:
    raise AssertionError("Error not raised")
```

Comment: You can catch more serializers by throwing the exception in [`__reduce__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__), but since that method is used by the copy protocol, things like [`copy.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.copy) will also stop working with your class. That can be fixed by implementing a `__copy__` method though (see the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module docs for details).